# Qual a diferença entre centralizar com "align-items: center" ou "margin"?

Tags: css, flexbox, margin

Eu vi que é possível centralizar uma `div` ou `img` com `display:flex`, `align-items: center` ou com o `margin`.

Qual a diferença entre esses dois para centralizar?

Answer (score 2):

De forma superficial: O align-items: center garante que os flex-items dentro de um elemento com display flex vão centralizar (verticalmente e horizontalmente).

Por margin você pode fazer a mesma coisa mas pode ser mais complicado por depender do tamanho do box (pai e filho), display e position. principalmente quando se trata de alinhamento vertical.

Answer (score 2):

A diferença é que a `margin:auto` alinha tanto na vertical quanto na horizontal ao mesmo tempo, ou seja ela vai centralizar o elemento que estiver dentro no eixo `X` e `Y` simultaneamente.

Já `justify-content: center;` vai alinhar centralizando só na horizontal (eixo `X`)

E `align-items: center;` vai alinhar centralizando só na vertical (eixo `Y`)

[image: **]

**Veja o código da imagem acima**

```css
body {  display: flex;}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.filho {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.jc {
  justify-content: center;
}

.ac {
  align-items: center;
}

.ma{
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box jc">
  <div class="filho">justify-content: center;</div>
</div>

<div class="box ac">
  <div class="filho">align-items: center;</div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div class="filho ma">margin: auto;</div>
</div>
```

Além disso, com `margin` vc pode ter auto só no eixo `X` ou no eixo `Y`, tipo `margin: 0 auto;` Esse código vai colocar margem `0` no eixo `Y` e `auto` no eixo `X`.

Já com `justify-content: center;` ou `align-items: center;` vc não vai conseguir controlar individualmente cada lado (direita ou esquerda), com essas duas opões o elemento filho sempre vai ficar alinhado proporcionalmente no centro exato. Já com margem vc poderia usar `margin-left: auto;` ou `margin-top: auto;` etc...

Cara a melhor forma de aprender é testando pega esse código ai de exemplo e vai brincando com ele mudando os valores das propriedades e vendo como funciona.